# What is the maximum voltage I can set up on the AFG2125 function generator?

Tags: function-generator, instrumentation

So, I'm picking up signals to work on the lab with the AFG2125 function generator. I have this generator on the lab https://www.gwinstek.com/en-global/products/downloadSeriesDownNew/5412/442 and on page2 it says:

> AMPLITUDE RANGE <20MHz : 1mVpp~10Vpp(50 ohm); 2mVpp~20Vpp(open-circuit)

My question is, should I care about the 50 ohm termination or the open-circuit generator. What is this 50 ohm termination thing? I need to use the maximum voltage possible, as my circuit will attenuate the signals a lot. But is 10Vpp the maximum I can do, or can I go for 20Vpp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to clarify something for your understanding. When you use 50 Ohm termination, the function generator is pretty much literally putting a 50 Ohm resistor in series with the signal inside the generator. So the max open circuit voltage will be 20V regardless of whether you use 50 Ohm termination or not.

If your load impedance is much higher than 50 Ohms, the termination will have little effect. For example, if you set the generator to 10Vpp with 50 Ohm termination, then look at the signal with an oscilloscope with high input impedance, it will still be 20Vpp. If you set the scope to 50 Ohm input impedance the signal will drop down to 10Vpp.

Hopefully, knowing this, you will be better able to make the decision about how you want to set up the function generator.

Answer (score 2):

What load impedance are you connecting it to?

If 50 ohms, use that figure.

If infinity, use the other figure.

If something in between, the voltage you get will be reduced from 20V p-p by a voltage divider, formed by its 50 ohm output impedance and your load.

So if you have a 1 kilohm load, you'll get 1000/1050 * 20Vp-p, or about 19V p-p.